# Why are the y-coordinates of my composable so different from their actual location on screen?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to retrieve the locations of card composables in a lazylist and then display a new composable on a surface above them at the same offset location but they offset values I get from the cards is so wildly different from the what is displayed on screen that sometimes they aren't even on the screen.

I am using the global position modifier to retrieve the location in the window then I am hoisting it out of the composables to a surface where I put a textbox at those same coordinates. I am using the local configuration to get the height and width of the screen and some y -values of the cards are 100s of dp away from where they are supposed to be. For some reason all the x-values are fine.

How I'm retrieving the coordinates. This card is populated with information from a repository and put in a lazylist of other such cards but when selected all the cards information is hoisted

```
    Card(                               
        Modifier
            .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                val positionInWindow = coordinates.positionInWindow()
                textboxLocation = IntOffset(
                    x = positionInWindow.x.toInt(),
                    y = positionInWindow.y.toInt()
                )
            }
```

How I take that hoisted value and use it to change the location of the textbox. Using padding instead of offset only makes it a little better.

```
    var clickLocation by remember { mutableStateOf(IntOffset(0,0)) }

    val updateHoistedLocation: (IntOffset) -> Unit = { newLocation ->
        clickLocation = newLocation}

         ...

    selected?.let {
        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier.offset(clickLocation.x.dp,clickLocation.y.dp),
```

I hope I have formatted this question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clickLocation.x.dp, clickLocation.y.dp or some Int value with `dp` extension is not correct way to convert from pixel to dp, let's say you get 100 from `positionInWindow.x.toInt()` in pixel adding dp to end makes it 100.dp while depending on device density it could be `50.dp` or `40.dp`.

It should be calculated with `pixel value/ density value` to able to create density independent pixel.

You can use `with(LocalDensity.current){clickLocation.x.toDp()}` or `LocalDensity.current.run{clickLocation.x.toDp()}` for both x and y.

```
/**
 * Convert an [Int] pixel value to [Dp].
 */
@Stable
fun Int.toDp(): Dp = (this / density).dp
```